# JQZoom Evolution 2.3 Not Zooming in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jqzoom

I'm using JQ Zoom Evolution 2.3 to zoom in on images in a Wordpress website. The issue I'm having is that the image isn't zooming in.

JQ Zoom resource page: http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/.

I've added the following into header.php

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.6.js'></script>  
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.jqzoom-core.js'></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jqzoom.css"> 

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){  
     $('.jqzoom').jqzoom();  
  });  

</script>
```

The js and css files have been uploaded to relevant directories.

The html is:

```
<a class="jqzoom" href="http://utopia.gerandeklerk.com/wp-content/uploads/chesterfield-large.jpg">
<img src="http://utopia.gerandeklerk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/chesterfield-small.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

The image is the leather sofa at the bottom of the page: http://utopia.gerandeklerk.com/full-width/.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's because the link to your chesterfield-large file is wrong. I think you mean for it to be

```
http://utopia.gerandeklerk.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/chesterfield-large.jpg
```

not

```
http://utopia.gerandeklerk.com/wp-content/uploads/chesterfield-large.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the URL, but it hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, if the page you're working on is the one you linked ( http://utopia.gerandeklerk.com/full-width/ ), at least from where I'm standing, you're still missing/have a number of broken links, including jquery and jqzoom. Forgive me if you already know it, but if you're using a recent Chrome or FireFox, hitting F12 will open a window that includes a network tab that can help you see where you're getting 404s.

Comment: thanks. I've correct the URL's in header.php: <script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-content/themes/utopia_tao/js/jquery-1.6.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-content/themes/utopia_tao/js/jquery.jqzoom-core.js'></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/utopia_tao/css/jquery.jqzoom.css">. The errors display the following: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://utopia.gerandeklerk.com/full-width/css/jquery.jqzoom.css. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The links in the generated HTML are different than that, though, and so the final page is still linking to the wrong location. Something (WordPress? PHP?) may be rewriting them for some reason. In any case, my guess is once you get the link issues sorted, you'll be up and running.